# Svelte transition: How to fade in, then out?

Tags: svelte

Using https://svelte.dev/tutorial/in-and-out as an example, how can I fade in, then fade out text on every click of the checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

A cheap way to do in-then-out is with a setTimeout

```
<script>
    import { fade, fly } from 'svelte/transition';
    let visible = true;
    
    const onClick = () => {
        visible = !visible;
        setTimeout(() => {
            visible = false;
        }, 500)
    }
</script>

<button on:click={onClick}>show, then hide</button>
```

Comment: This toggles fade-in/fade-out, not a paired fade-in-then-out in a single animation. I think the real solution will involve custom css transition, but I am not 100% sure yet.

Comment: Gotcha, so you want it to literally show then hide after a little